# Overloading library class constructor

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I'm dealing with the following problem. I'm using a library and would like to overload a constructor of a class in that library to better suit my needs. The library class provides a constructor like this:

```
public SomeName(int variable) {...}
```

and I would like to be able to call

```
public SomeName(int variable, float myVariable) {...}
```

Creating a Factory for that seems to be an overkill, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are you able to extend this library class?
or is it a final class?

Comment: I am able to do that, I was only hoping I could abuse java to do my bidding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java language does not provide any high level constructs that will allow you to change the superclass's constructors without altering the class code itself.

That said, there are alternatives. Mainly, you could use [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) to "inject" bytecode into the library and create your own constructors (through several advanced techniques).

That is absolutely **not** recommended for most coding tasks and the best solution to your problem (assuming you're not doing something non-trivial), is just subclassing that class:

```
class SomeName {
    public SomeName(int variable) {
        ...
    }
}

class OtherName extends SomeName {
    public OtherName(float otherVariable) {
        this(*DEFAULT*, otherVariable);
    }

    public OtherName(int variable, float otherVariable) {
        super(variable);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is just what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that without altering the library.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass that class and add new constructor :)

Answer (score 1):

`extend` the class and create a new constructor, because you can not do it without altering the lib.

Comment: Just create a new class extending your actual class, add a constructor of your own and use that. It would be enough.